# Checking three values are consecutive

Tags: java, rags-to-riches

This question was recently asked: [Determining if three numbers are consecutive](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94813/determining-if-three-numbers-are-consecutive)

It intrigued me, even though it was broken. I have the following implementation I thought would be interesting, and I am looking for reviews on readability, usability, and for any edge cases it may miss, etc.

```
/**
 * Determine whether three <code>int</code> values can be arranged in to an incrementing sequence.
 * 
 * @param a the first value
 * @param b the second value
 * @param c the third value
 * @return true if there is an order of the three inputs which makes them sequential
 */
public static final boolean isSequential(int a, int b, int c) {
    final int x = Math.abs(a - b);
    final int y = Math.abs(b - c);
    final int z = Math.abs(a - c);
    return x + y + z == 4 && x * y * z == 2;
}
```

I put this together in a unit test. Here's the full file:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ThreeInARow {

    /**
     * Determine whether three <code>int</code> values can be arranged in to an incrementing sequence.
     * 
     * @param a the first value
     * @param b the second value
     * @param c the third value
     * @return true if there is an order of the three inputs which makes them sequential
     */
    public static final boolean isSequential(int a, int b, int c) {
        final int x = Math.abs(a - b);
        final int y = Math.abs(b - c);
        final int z = Math.abs(a - c);
        return x + y + z == 4 && x * y * z == 2;
    }

    private static final int[] FROM = {Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE + 3, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
            0, 1, 2, 3, 100, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2, Integer.MAX_VALUE};


    @Test
    public void testGoodBlocks() {

        for (int f : FROM) {
            int a = f;
            int b = a + 1;
            int c = b + 1;
            Assert.assertTrue(isSequential(a, b, c));
            Assert.assertTrue(isSequential(b, c, a));
            Assert.assertTrue(isSequential(c, a, b));
            Assert.assertTrue(isSequential(b, a, c));
            Assert.assertTrue(isSequential(a, c, b));
            Assert.assertTrue(isSequential(c, b, a));
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testBadBlocks() {

        for (int f : FROM) {
            int a = f;
            int b = a + 1;
            int c = b + 2;
            Assert.assertFalse(isSequential(a, b, c));
            Assert.assertFalse(isSequential(b, c, a));
            Assert.assertFalse(isSequential(c, a, b));
            Assert.assertFalse(isSequential(b, a, c));
            Assert.assertFalse(isSequential(a, c, b));
            Assert.assertFalse(isSequential(c, b, a));
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testSpecials() {
        int[][] specials = {
                {0,0,0},
                {1,0,1},
                {0,0,1}
        };
        for (int[] attempt : specials) {
            Assert.assertFalse(isSequential(attempt[0], attempt[1], attempt[2]));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Edge case?

I tried your function with:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
Integer.MIN_VALUE
Integer.MIN_VALUE+1
```

and it returned true.  I don't know if wraparounds are supposed to be accepted or not, but with your function they are.

Comment: Good catch, but I wouldn't care. Most things break near the limits, so I guess, it's acceptable.

Comment: Hmmm ... I do care ;-) I added some other extreme test cases, but I did not think of wrap-around cases. I like this answer, and I think it counts... now I have to decide whether it should be solved with code, or documentation,

Comment: Well, someone in the other question used a sort.  That would give a different answer than this.  So it depends on how you define consecutive.

Answer (score 12):

I don't like the idea of having to solve Diophantine equations just to be able to understand the code.  I'll suggest the same solution here as I did for @cody.codes:

```
public static boolean isSequential(int a, int b, int c) {
    int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
    int max = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
    return max - min == 2 && a != b && a != c && b != c;
}
```

"The minimum and maximum differ by 2, and all three numbers are unique" is easier to understand.

Comment: You may want to convert `min` and `max` to `long` so that `Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE` (or some other select values) don't break.

Comment: @KenzieTogami I can't think of any situation where overflow would break this logic, though.

Comment: I suppose that's true.

Answer (score 6):

The expression

```
x + y + z == 4 && x * y * z == 2;
```

is a bit code-golfing. Not only are `x`, `y`, and `z` themselves susceptible to overflow for the wrap-around case as [JS shows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94831/14363), but you can get unlucky with the multiplication overflowing. A search for such solutions could be a funny exercise.

To make it more funny, the addition can overflow, too.

---

Your expression could be replaced by

```
Math.min(x, y, z) == 1 && Math.max(x, y, z) == 2
```

if we had such three-operand functions. Using Guava, it could be replaced by

```
ImmutableMultiset.of(x, y, z).equals(ImmutableMultiset.of(1, 1, 2))
```

which would be pretty inefficient, but it'd exactly express the intention. Finally, you could count the occurrences of 1, just like I did in [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94848/14363).

---

Concerning tests, I'd look at all values around `0`, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and maybe `Integer.MAX_VALUE/3`. This would require a simple surely correct method for determining the result. But given the multiplication overflow problem, such tests are still too weak.

You'd actually need a correctness proof. While the [overflow problem detected by JS] might be seen as a feature or avoided by using `long`, the multiplication overflow may be worse:

- it may happen for moderately big numbers
- it can't be prevented using `long`

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring integer wraparound the second condition suffices.

The only way \$x \cdot y \cdot z = 2\$ for \$x,y,z \in \mathbb{N} \$ is if one and only one of \$\{x, y, z\}\$ is equal to \$2\$ and the rest are equal to \$1\$.

If \$\mid\> a-b \mid = 1\$ and \$\mid\> b-c \mid = 1\$ then either \$c = a\$ or \$c = a\pm 2\$.

If \$c = a \pm 2\$ then \$b\$ must be between \$a\$ and \$c\$ since it is equidistant from them both (this is 1D).

Comment: Nicely done, and another really good point.

Comment: Note that this will identify `{Integer.MIN_VALUE, -1, 1}` ... ;-) A different edge case.

Answer (score 0):

To evade overflow in `x + y + z == 4 && x * y * z == 2` (the product may exceed `long`), check for `(x|y|z) == 3`. "The other condition" may be 
`x * y * z == 2` or `x + y + z == 4` (`(x^y^z) == 2` fails for {0, 1, 3}).